# Facing Issues with Chrome Driver while trying to create a script for taking screenshots of a website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, webpage-screenshot

So I tried the following code to install the Web Driver based on by chrome version and this is the error I get

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Set up Chrome WebDriver using webdriver_manager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lavanya/Learn Python/pythonProject/PythonCTSPOC/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 118, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 217, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 432, in urlopen
    conn = self.connection_from_host(u.host, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 303, in connection_from_host
    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 328, in connection_from_context
    return self.connection_from_pool_key(pool_key, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 351, in connection_from_pool_key
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 265, in _new_pool
    return pool_cls(host, port, **request_context)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 196, in __init__
    timeout = Timeout.from_float(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 190, in from_float
    return Timeout(read=timeout, connect=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 119, in __init__
    self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, "connect")
  File "C:\Users\Lavanya\anaconda3\envs\PythonCTSPOC\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 156, in _validate_timeout
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x00000136338C90D0>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

Have tried manually giving the path for the chrome driver and it still doesn't work

This is the code I'm working with

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
import time

chrome_driver_path = r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe"  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

url = "https://www.youtube.com/"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5.0)
driver.save_screenshot("image3.png")
image1 = Image.open("image3.png")

driver.quit()
```

My Chrome Version is 118.0.5993.118 and I'm not sure where to find the Web Driver for this.